# Edit CSS to eliminate margin on end of column

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a display container with a flexible width which contains `li` items that float left.
There are margins set so the `li` elements form a grid.

**Question**: How can I set the last `li` on the right to have `margin-right:0`
so that the grid can be lined up perfectly against the back drop?

[image]

I have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/g9H2u/), and my code right now is as follows:

*CSS*:

```
html, body{margin:0; padding:0; }
.topNav { left:0; right:0; position:absolute; top:0px;
     margin:0 30px 0 30px; text-align:center; height:100px; background-color:grey;
}

.content { margin:130px 30px 0 30px; padding:0; background-color:#999; display:block; float:left; }
.content li{ width:180px; height:280px; background-color:#333; float:left; list-style:none; 
    /* margin:0 0 20px 20px; */
    margin:0 20px 20px 0;
}
.last{clear:both; width:10px; height:10px;  background-color:#999;}
```

*HTML*:

```
<div class="topNav">
</div>

<ul class='content'>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <div class='last'></div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9H2u/2/)**

One of the solutions is to use both `left` and `right` margin for your `li`s.
Change the `margin` of your `content` to this:

```
.content { margin: 130px 20px 0 20px; }
```

Note that I reduce it from `30` to `20`. Now set the `margin` of `li` to this:

```
.content li { margin: 0 10px 20px 10px; }
```

Note that instead of adding `20` margin to `left` or `right`, I added `10` to each.

---

### Background

If you want to keep the background of your `content`, you must change your markup:

```
<div class="ul-container">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    <ul class='content'>
        <li></li>
        <!-- more list item -->
        <li class='last'></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then add this rules in CSS:

```
.content { position: relative; }

.ul-container .bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    background: yellow;
}
```

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9H2u/4/)**

Comment: thanks!  but then how can i match the bg-color so that it all fits in without margins on the sides? you can see the edges have a sliver now: http://jsfiddle.net/nalagg/g9H2u/3/

Comment: @tq For that, you must change a little your markup, check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9H2u/4/) and you will find out `;)`.

Comment: @steveax Can you tell me please, where I have a `div` as a child of `ul`?

Comment: @NOX looks like I may have been conflating the OP's fiddle with yours. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
ulSelector > li:last-child{
   margin-right:0;
}
```

Comment: This will only fix it for the very last `li` in the `ul`, not for the ones which are wrapped earlier.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out immediately after posting my answer. I would typically use a solution like NOX suggested; or I would JS to align the containers on the fly.